# Don't allow whitespace for regex in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I modify this regex to not accept whitespaces.

```
return [
               'file' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1500',
               'name' => 'required',
             'tel_no' => 'regex:/^[-0-9\+\s]+$/',
            'address' => 'required',
        ];
```

Comment: @Calimero I already removed it but somehow it still accepts whitespaces

Comment: @Calimero Will I add another brackets or some sort?

Comment: no @Calimero `^` means "start of line", `$` means "end of line"

Comment: you could give this a try : 'regex:/^[-0-9\+^\s]+$/' (you're right @tino.codes, my bad again, thanks for the clarification)

Comment: @Calimero It still doesn't work :( Do I have to provide two regular expressions?

Comment: at this point the regexp is fine (so would the one provided by @tino.codes btw), so your problem must originate somewhere else in your app. Is your input validation run as it should ?

Comment: @Calimero The validation works if I input numbers and with whitespaces but if I only enter whitespace it will accept it.

Comment: Do you accept spaces between numbers? What format do you accept?

Comment: @Amarnasan my textbox is for contact numbers , if i type "143-5 555" it will send an error but if I only type a blank space in the text box it will accept it. I want to avoid this problem wherein a user just inputs a blank space I don't want to accept it.

Comment: The desired format is still not clear

Answer (score 0):

```
'tel_no' => 'required|regex:/^\+?\d+(-\d+)*?$/'
```

Comment: it's still the same, when I type " 1" or "1 " or "255 555" , it won't accept it but if I type a single blank space and press save, it will accept it.

Comment: I want to trap an input where the user just inputs a single blank space and accept only numbers, dash and the plus symbol. It is used for my contact number textbox.

Comment: @arthlimchiu : This regex requires it not to be empty, to start and finish with a digit, and spaces and dash are allowed between numbers, OR a single whitespace.

Comment: @arthlimchiu You're mixing what you want and what is actually happening. Can you just list the entries you want to accept?

Comment: What I want are 0-9 digits, + symbol, and dash symbol. What I don't want are numbers with spaces, letters, and an input that is only a blank space

Comment: @arthlimchiu Ok, you got it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

remove the `\s`

```
return [
               'file' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1500',
               'name' => 'required',
             'tel_no' => 'required|regex:/^[-0-9\+]+$/',
            'address' => 'required',
        ];
```

Comment: I already removed it but somehow it still accepts whitespaces.

Comment: The validation works if I input numbers with white spaces but if I only input a white space it will accept it.

Comment: Like Amarnasan mentioned, you have to add a `required` validation